# Loop through days/weeks/months/years since date (swift)

Tags: swift

I'm developing a financial application, where users can set **daily/weekly/monthly/yearly limits**.

I'd like to create a table which displays those limits: grouped, from the date user added the limit 'till the current date

**Today is 2020 may 1**

---

## Example

User adds a **"Weekly limit"** on **2020 april 15**

Then I'd like to display the following cells:

- **2020 april 13 - 2020 april 19** *(first week)*
- **2020 april 20 - 2020 april 26** *(second week)*
- **2020 april 27 - 2020 may 3** *(third week)*

---

## Example 2

User adds a **"Monthly limit"** on **2020 january 10**

Then I'd like to display the following cells:

- **January** *(first month)*
- **February** *(second month)*
- **March** *(third month)*
- **April** *(fourth month)*
- **May** *(fifth month)*

---

And the same with daily / yearly limits.

How could I achieve that?

```
class Spare {
    static let shared = Spare()

    var limits : [Limit] = [] // Here do I store the limits

    func tableGenerateLimits() -> [Limit] {
        // ???
    }
}
class Limit : NSObject {

    var id : Double
    var date : Date
    var value : Int

    var type : LimitType = .weekly

    init(id : Double? = nil, date : Date, value: Int, type : LimitType){
        self.id = id ?? NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
        self.date = date
        self.value = value
        self.type = type

        super.init()
    }
}
```

I'm completely lost

Answer (score 0):

First you can create a `Date()` object, then use a `Calendar` object to get your values you'll need for all these calculations.

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
var year = 0
var month = 0
var day = 0
```

Then you can get a specific date to return by doing something like this.

```
let toDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: someDayFutureOrPast, to date)
```

Once you have your specific date stored as a variable you can then simply grab it out of the `calendar` like so.

```
let year = calendar.component(.year, from: toDate!)
let month = calendar.component(.month, from: toDate!)
let day = calendar.component(.day, from: toDate!)
```

Since you're working with cells you'll want to place a method to get this from within your `tableView(cellForRowAt...)` method somewhere, or wherever works for you.

Here's a method that will get exactly what you want. I've returned a tuple for simplicity's sake but you can convert it however you need. Apologies for any syntax errors. I'm not on my Mac, nor is it near me atm.

```
func getDate(dateFromCurrent: Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) {
    let date = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    var year = 0
    var month = 0
    var day = 0
    let toDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: someDayFutureOrPast, to date)

return (calendar.component(.year, from: toDate!), 
        calendar.component(.month, from: toDate!),
        calendar.component(.day, from: toDate!)
}
```

*NOTE* You can go `BACK IN TIME` by changing the `someDayFutureOrPast` to a negative int.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on `DateComponents` and the `Calendar` class.

For instance to get the correct dates for the week, get the weekday from a given date and then calculate the diff. Then use the diff to adjust the given date to the start date for the week and calculate the end date

```
let calendar = Calendar.current

var weekday = calendar.dateComponents([.weekday], from: today)
var diff = weekday.weekday! - calendar.firstWeekday
if diff < 0 { diff += 7}
let startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -diff, to: today)
let endDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 6, to: startDate!)!
```

Then you can get more start and end dates by using the same `Calendar` function to add but use `.week` instead. Something like

```
let nextStart = calendar.date(byAdding: .week, value: 1, to: startDate)
```

but perhaps in a loop.

For months you use the Calendar again to extract the month from the given date

```
let month = calendar.dateComponents([.month], from: today).month!
```

And then you can use the array of month names using `monthSymbols` to get the five months

```
for i in month..<(month + 5) {
    let index = i > 12 ? i - 13 : i - 1
    print(calendar.monthSymbols[index])
}
```